# how to use do loop to read several files with similar names in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have several files named scale1.dat, scale2.dat scale3.dat ... up to scale9.dat.

I want to read these files in do loop one by one and with each file I want to do some manipulation (I want to write the 1st column of each scale*.dat file to scale*.txt).

So my question is, is there a way to read files with similar names. Thanks.

Comment: `for SCALE in scale{1..9}.dat; do process $SCALE; done`

Comment: This is not working. I have several files with names like scale1.dat scale2.dat.... scale9.dat .... I want to have 1st scale1.dat and do something, next scale2.dat and do same thing and so on.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?!

Comment: I want to write the 1st column of each scale*.dat file to scale*.txt

        for SCALE in scale{1..9}.dat;
        do process $SCALE
        awk '{ print $1 }' $SCALE > $SCALE.txt
        done
its returning  line 2: process: command not found

Comment: That's because `process` is not a valid command name, not because there is anything wrong with the loop syntax.

Comment: But you should properly have `"$SCALE"` in double quotes, always.

Comment: You should mention that in your questions! Replace `process` in my sample with that operation, i.e. with awk: `for SCALE in scale{1..9}.dat; do awk  '{ print $1 }' $SCALE > $(basename $SCALE .dat).txt; done`

Comment: But is it possible to read each file (scale1.dat, next scale2.dat and so on) one by one and do some manipulation/algebra ? Like 1st read scale1.dat and do some algebra with the columns and save it to output_scale1.txt and take scale2.dat and do same algebra and save it to output_scale2.txt and so on ??

Answer (score 0):

The regular syntax for this is

```
for file in scale*.dat; do
    awk '{print $1}' "$file" >"${file%.dat}.txt"
done
```

The asterisk `*` matches any text or no text; if you want to constrain to just single non-zero digits, you could say `for file in scale[1-9].dat` instead.

In Bash, there is a non-standard additional glob syntax `scale{1..9}.dat` but this is Bash-only, and so will not work in `#!/bin/sh` scripts.  (Your question has both [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) so it's not clear which you require.  Your comment that the Bash syntax is not working for you suggests that you may need a POSIX portable solution.) Furthermore, Bash has something called extended globbing, which allows for quite elaborate pattern matching.  See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

For a simple task like this, you don't really need the shell at all, though.

```
awk 'FNR==1 { if (f) close (f); f=FILENAME; sub(/\.dat/, ".txt", f); }
    { print $1 >f }' scale[1-9]*.dat
```

(Okay, maybe that's slightly intimidating for a first-timer. But the basic point is that you will often find that the commands you want to use will happily work on multiple files, and so you don't need shell loops at all in those cases.)

Comment: Actually I wanted to read at first scale1.dat and do some manipulation/algebra with its columns and finally wanted a output like output_scale1.txt, next I want to read scale2.dat and do same manipulation/algebra and finally want output_scale2.txt... and so on.....
Is it possible?

Comment: This answer already does that.  It trims off the `.dat` extension and writes the first column to the corresponding `.txt` file.  The variable interpolation `${var%suf}` produces the value of `var` with any suffix `suf` removed. Thus `${file%.dat}.txt` is the value of `file` with any `.dat` suffix removed and `.txt` tacked on at the end instead.  Obviously you can add `output_` in front as well.

Comment: Okay I understand. But I wanted to know, in this way is it taking 1st scale1.dat and then scale2.dat and so on? Is there a way to get the numbers i.e. from scale1.dat 1, scale2.dat 2 etc.

Comment: Globs are always expanded in alphabetic order.  If you have multiple globs, each is expanded separately.  So if you have `file1 file2 gile1 gile2` then the expression `*1 f*` will expand to `file1 gile1 file1 file2`.where the first two are due to the first glob, and the next two to the other. But this is becoming significant enough to warrant a separate question; or go ahead and visit the link I included (again?)

Comment: To extract a substring from a file name, you can do `pref=${file%.dat}` to obtain just the base name, then `num=${pref##*[!0-9]}` to strip off everything up to the last non-number.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. Similar names or not, you will have to iterate through all your files (perhaps with a `for` loop) and use a nested loop to iterate through lines or words or whatever you plan to read from those files.

Alternatively, you can copy your files into one (say, `scale-all.dat`) and read that single file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I wanted to avoid the 2nd alternative.